# How to do parallel processing in the neural network to reduce training time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, parallel-processing

I am trying to do parallel processing in neural network such that different processes can be taken my multiple CPU's and then it should reduce the training time. My deep learning model code and parallel processing code is shown below, I do not how to combine both of them:

**Code of Model:**

```
from tensorflow import *
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from imutils import paths
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import argparse
import os

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", type=str,
    default="mask_detector.model",
    help="path to output face mask detector model")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# initialize the initial learning rate, number of epochs to train for,
# and batch size
INIT_LR = 1e-4
EPOCHS = 20
BS = 32

# grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
# the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
print("[INFO] loading images...")
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))
data = []
labels = []

# loop over the image paths
for imagePath in imagePaths:
    # extract the class label from the filename
    label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]

    # load the input image (224x224) and preprocess it
    image = load_img(imagePath, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = preprocess_input(image)

    # update the data and labels lists, respectively
    data.append(image)
    labels.append(label)

# convert the data and labels to NumPy arrays
data = np.array(data, dtype="float32")
labels = np.array(labels)

# perform one-hot encoding on the labels
lb = LabelBinarizer()
labels = lb.fit_transform(labels)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# partition the data into training and testing splits using 75% of
# the data for training and the remaining 25% for testing
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
    test_size=0.20, stratify=labels, random_state=42)

# construct the training image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=20,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")

# load the MobileNetV2 network, ensuring the head FC layer sets are
# left off
baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
    input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))

# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(128, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the first training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

# compile our model
print("[INFO] compiling model...")
opt = Adam(lr=INIT_LR, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
    metrics=["accuracy"])

# train the head of the network
print("[INFO] training head...")
H = model.fit(
    aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
    steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
    validation_data=(testX, testY),
    validation_steps=len(testX) // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)

# make predictions on the testing set
print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
predIdxs = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)

# for each image in the testing set we need to find the index of the
# label with corresponding largest predicted probability
predIdxs = np.argmax(predIdxs, axis=1)

# show a nicely formatted classification report
print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1), predIdxs,
    target_names=lb.classes_))

# serialize the model to disk
print("[INFO] saving mask detector model...")
model.save(args["model"], save_format="h5")
```

**Code of Parallel processing:**

```
import math
import numpy as np
from timebudget import timebudget
from multiprocessing import Pool

iterations_count = round(1e7)

def complex_operation(input_index):
    print("Complex operation. Input index: {:2d}\n".format(input_index))
    [math.exp(i) * math.sinh(i) for i in [1] * iterations_count]

@timebudget
def run_complex_operations(operation, input, pool):
    pool.map(operation, input)

processes_count = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes_pool = Pool(processes_count)
    run_complex_operations(complex_operation, range(10), processes_pool)
```

Above parallel processing code is just sample, Anybody having an idea to how to embed or do parallel computing to save the training time of neural network

Answer (score 0):

Unless you wrote entire training code yourself (which does not seem to be the case given that you are using TF) it is not a right approach. You are already using a library that hides all the computational details from you, look at how TF/Keras/whatever you are using can utilise all your CPUs/GPUs, they are all built to scale, and are much more efficient than trying to wrap something around them. In particular TF itself should automatically use all your CPUs.

Comment: @leijot , I am using Tensorflow and Keras. Actually , you are saying true , when I starts training of notebook , i dont know why it is using all cores of CPU's. Client is saying to me that you may use any parallel computing to save time for training. I dont know how 